# About standard Laplace distribution

Tags: statistics

I've been doing my homework and I had some problems with my last exercise. Supose that $X\sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$ and $U\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ and define $$Y = \begin{cases}
 X & \text{if}\hspace{0.2cm} U> 0.5, \\
 -X & \text{if}\hspace{0.2cm} U\leq 0.5.
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that $Y$ have a standard Laplace distribution.

I don't know how to start it, if anyone can give a hint or something I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual way that we define a variable which has the distribution of $X_k$ with probability $p_k$, where $k=1,2,\dots,n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = 1$. The key is that $U$ and $X$ are independent (which you have not stated; the result may not be true otherwise).

Here's a hint for how to start the formal proof. Use the total probability formula:

$$P(Y \leq y)=P(Y \leq y\mid U \leq 1/2)P(U \leq 1/2) + P(Y \leq y\mid U > 1/2) P(U>1/2)$$

Now when $U \leq 1/2$, $Y$ has the distribution of $-X$, and when $U > 1/2$, $Y$ has the distribution of $X$. That and the independence of $X$ and $U$ will let you calculate the conditional probabilities.

Comment: Hi! In my homework doesn't appears if $U$ and $X$ are independent, but I think so! Thanks so much! Now I know how to finish the problem :)